how to upload images dataset in ecl watch and spray it, i tried using blob format but caused multiple problems
My problem: brain tumour detection using CNN in ecl. i am uploading the image dataset (the images are converted to strings) but when i spray it the no of columns do not match up to the dataset
I am absolute beginner in ecl

The BLOB spray is designed to create two fields in the target sprayed file to the THOR cluster. A filename field and a DATA field with the compressed contents of each image (the image is stored as hexadecimal bytes).
It would be helpful to know what errors you are seeing. Also, please refer to this article for proper use of the BLOB spray option:
Working with BLOBs
Regards,
Bob
